# Can't Speak/Voice to SwiftUI Textfield

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, voice

I was about to publish a SwiftUI app today when I was astounded to find that voice
input to my textfields did not work. When tapping the microphone on the keyboard the
textfield registers one character and beeps to end voice input (once in a while
I got two characters). So I did the super basic project with one textfield to prove
it was not something else in my app. I have not been able to find any info in the
Apple documentation nor here on SO that states that a modifier is needed for 
this purpose.

The simplest of code:

```
@State private var firstTextField = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Start with a Label")
        TextField("Field One", text: $firstTextField)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            .padding()

        Text("Field One is \(self.firstTextField)")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

For the photo below I spoke "This is the first field". This was the result:

[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

Comment: i am not sure, but just an idea...did you set privacy settings for micro in info.plist?

Comment: Yes, I did so. But the behavior was the same with and without that plist item. And the same is true if you add voice recognition in plist

Comment: "Astounded" is a nice way of saying it.  I was mad as hell when I found this in my app yesterday and it makes me question what else is totally broken in SwiftUI.   This approach helped me: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/128721